# 70s Sci Fi book with an alien on Earth with a light sword that could be used like a lasso

Tags: story-identification, novel

I read a book in the late 70s, when I was about 11 or 12 years old so my memory is foggy, about a man on Earth from another planet and his space ship was disabled.  He had a weapon like a lightsaber but it could also be used to grab you like a lasso. He came to Earth as a scout from another planet.  I vaguely remember he had a pet, possibly a miniature dragon or winged serpent with him.  He was a good guy, trying to help people around him.

I think also there was an antagonist, an Earth man that wanted his technology. This would have come out after *Star Wars*, I think that is where the lightsaber like weapon got its inspiration.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  This is a bit thin on details; check out the [suggestions](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/101407) for asking good story-id questions to see if they help you recall any more information you can [edit] into your question.

Comment: Do the names Flinx and Pip ring any bells?